# Create SiteMap in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I Want Create SiteMap For ASP.NET MVC Site. I Write This Code

```
[XmlRoot("urlset", Namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")]
    public class Sitemap
    {
        private ArrayList _map;

        public Sitemap()
        {
            _map = new ArrayList();
        }

        [XmlElement("url")]
        public Location[] Locations
        {
            get
            {
                Location[] items = new Location[_map.Count];
                _map.CopyTo(items);
                return items;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    return;
                var items = (Location[])value;
                _map.Clear();
                foreach (Location item in items)
                    _map.Add(item);
            }
        }

        public int Add(Location item)
        {
            return _map.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public enum EChangeFrequency
        {
            Always,
            Hourly,
            Daily,
            Weekly,
            Monthly,
            Yearly,
            Never
        }

        [XmlElement("loc")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("changefreq")]
        public EChangeFrequency? ChangeFrequency { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeChangeFrequency() { return ChangeFrequency.HasValue; }

        [XmlElement("lastmod")]
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeLastModified() { return LastModified.HasValue; }

        [XmlElement("priority")]
        public double? Priority { get; set; }
        public bool ShouldSerializePriority() { return Priority.HasValue; }
    }

    public class XmlResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly object _objectToSerialize;

        public XmlResult(object objectToSerialize)
        {
            _objectToSerialize = objectToSerialize;
        }

        public object ObjectToSerialize
        {
            get { return _objectToSerialize; }
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (_objectToSerialize != null)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(_objectToSerialize.GetType());
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                xs.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, _objectToSerialize);
            }
        }
    }
```

and Create `Sitemap` Action in `NewsFeedController` Like This

```
 public ActionResult Sitemap()
        {
            var sm = new Sitemap();
            sm.Add(new Location()
            {
                Url = string.Format("http://www.TechnoDesign.ir/Articles/{0}/{1}", 1, "SEO-in-ASP.NET-MVC"),
                LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Priority = 0.5D
            });
            return new XmlResult(sm);
        }
```

and In `RouteConfig` Define New Route For SiteMap Like This

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {


            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                  "SiteMap_route", // Route name
                  "sitemap.xml", // URL with parameters
                  new { controller = "NewsFeed", action = "Sitemap", name = UrlParameter.Optional, area = "" }, // Parameter defaults
                   namespaces: new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
              );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
            );

        }
```

But When Enter `/sitemap.xml` get `error 404`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had this same issue for [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for MVC 4 and up. We solved it by removing and then replacing the `UrlRoutingModule` in the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a route with a file extension at the end (.xml) is not allowed in MVC 5 and below (MVC 6 is fine), so you need to add the line below in your Web.config file.

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="SitemapXml" path="sitemap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```